# RecyclerView's children onTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch-event, android-recyclerview

I'm working with RecyclerView and recently I added a 3 dots menu on every row that should open a PopoupWindow. The problem is that I can't manage to handle the touch on the 3 dots menu icon because the row consumes the touch event. I'm messing around with the onInterceptTouchEvent but I can't find a way to detect touch on the menu..

Here is basically my RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener code:

```
    public class RecyclerItemTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {

        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        //need a way to detect if the user touches the menu icon!!
        boolean touchOccurredOnMenu = ?????;

        if(childView != null && touchOccurredOnMenu) {

            //here the menu will handle the touch event
            return false;

        }


        //here the recycler item will handle the touch event
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "touch on the row", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

I set the touchListener for the menu icon in the onBindViewHolder method of the RecyclerView.Adapter like this:

```
holder.overflowMenuIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "touch on the menu!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try adding android:focusable="false" in the row that consumes the touch event.?

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the touches on the row will start a new activity so I can't set the focusable attribute to false..

Comment: I dont think setting focusable=false will not make it unclickable. It will just say whether the view can take focus.

Comment: Still doesn't work with focusable=false

Comment: Do you have found a cool solution for your issue? My solution is to use onClickListener inside the Adapter for each item and view,but i do not like that.

Comment: Sadly no.. I did exactly what you did at the end

Comment: I used the solution given by Mr. Anthony Lenz in his blog http://lenz-tech.blogspot.com/2015/05/adding-context-menus-to-recyclerview.html , works great

Comment: for future use, https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnItemTouchListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener) is where you shouldve set your interface, not on the holder. This handles scrolling of the recycler view and touching of individual items.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when adding an overflow button to my RecyclerView's rows. The trick is, in your Gesture Detector, you get the viewholder for the view that was clicked, calculate the hit rectangle coordinates for your button ("overflow" in my case) and, if the hit rectangle contains the event coordinates, you consume the event, otherwise you do your row click.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(mTouchListener);
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), new RecyclerViewOnGestureListener());
```

with

```
private final RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener mTouchListener = new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    }
};
```

and

```
private class RecyclerViewOnGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        View view = mRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = view != null ? mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) : null;
        View overflow = viewHolder != null ? ((DataViewHolder) viewHolder).mOverflow : null;
        if (overflow != null) {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            overflow.getHitRect(rect);
            rect.top += view.getTop();
            rect.bottom += view.getTop();
            int x = (int) (e.getX() + .5f);
            int y = (int) (e.getY() + .5f);
            if (!rect.contains(x, y)) {
                onClick(view);
            }
            // else event consumed by overflow button
        } else {
            onClick(view);
        }
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `.5f` ?

Comment: That's to round the float value to the closest int, as opposed to truncating the float to an int. You can skip that if you want.